# Setting a parameter as optional

Tags: python, arguments

Is there a way in Python to set a parameter as optional (ignore it as if it wasn't there)?

What I mean is, suppose you have a class like:

```
class RandomClass():

    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.lst())

    def lst(self):
        return [self.x, self.y, self.z]
```

and you try to run this:

```
r1 = RandomClass(1,2,3)
r1.lst()
[1, 2, 3]
print(r1)
[1, 2, 3]
```

this works, but if you were to try something like: `r1 = RandomClass(1,2)` it will fail.

So if setting parameters to be optional is possible then these should work fine:

```
r1 = RandomClass(1,2)
r1 = RandomClass(1,2,3)
```

Example (suppose `z` is set as optional) then:

```
   r1 = RandomClass(1,2)
   r1.lst()
   [1, 2, None]
   print(r1)
   [1, 2, None]
```

I set the optional parameter to put None if not used, but it can be anything, like 0, 2, etc to identify that is not being used.

So do you think this is even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set default values to parameters. In this case you want that `z` can be given or not by the user. So, you can set its default value to `None` if the user gives 2 arguments to the constructor:

```
class RandomClass(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z=None):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z  # here, z will be None if only 2 arguments are passed

    # other methods...


[...]
>>> r1 = RandomClass(1,2)
>>> r1.lst()
[1, 2, None]
```

Make sure that optional arguments are always at the end of the parameter list (It's impossible to write something like `__init__(self, x=None, y, z)`). I advise you to read this tutorial : [Using Optional and Named Arguments](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/optional_arguments.html), from http://www.diveintopython.net/.

Comment: Thanks Maxime! didn't realize I can assign a default value to a variable in the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example method, a function with two optional arguments:

```
def method(noDefault, arg1=10, arg2=1):
```

*"arg1"* and *"arg2"* **are optional**, because they have **default values defined**. 
*"noDefault"* is required, because it has **no default value**.

 If *"method"* is **called with only one argument**, the following will happen 
 **arg1 defaults to 10** 
 **arg2 defaults to 1**.
 
If *method* **is called with two arguments**, 
**arg2 still defaults to 1.**